# Sudoku Solver in CPLEX

Tags: java, mathematical-optimization, sudoku, cplex

I am trying to solve a Sudoku program that I created.
This is the Objective Function

```
IloNumExpr numExpr = cplex.linearNumExpr();
cplex.addMaximize(numExpr);
```

What I am trying to do is to add to this either a constraint or new objective function that will allow for the four corner points in the 9x9 Sudoku matrix have special preference in the order of `5 > 7 > 4 > 6 > 8 > 2 > 3 > 9 > 1`

Any ideas on what mathematical formulation is needed to complete this?

Answer (score 1):

You'd impose the preference order by adding elements to your Objective Function.

Let's say you have variables of the type

#### choose[row][col][digit]

If choose[2][3][8] = 1 it means that the square (2,3) has the value 8.

The four corners are:
1,1; 1,9;
9,1; 9,9

Essentially, you need to add the following to your existing objective function.

```
9 x choose[1][1][5] + 8 x choose[1][1][7] + 7 x choose[1][1][4] + ... + 2 x choose[1][1][9] + 1 x choose[1][1][1]
9 x choose[1][9][5] + 8 x choose[1][9][7] + 7 x choose[1][9][4] + ... + 2 x choose[1][9][9] + 1 x choose[1][9][1]
9 x choose[9][1][5] + 8 x choose[9][1][7] + 7 x choose[9][1][4] + ... + 2 x choose[9][1][9] + 1 x choose[9][1][1]
9 x choose[9][9][5] + 8 x choose[9][9][7] + 7 x choose[9][9][4] + ... + 2 x choose[9][1][9] + 1 x choose[9][9][1]
```

#### In CPLEX

// Preference order: 5 > 7 > 4 > 6 > 8 > 2 > 3 > 9 > 1

```
  int[]  preferenceOrder;
  preferenceOrder[1] = 9;
  preferenceOrder[2] = 8;  
  preferenceOrder[8] = 2; 
  preferenceOrder[9] = 1;
  cplex.addMaximize(cplex.scalProd(preferenceOrder, choose));
```

#### Why this works?

The CPLEX Solver tries to maximize the value of the obj function. All else being equal, it will first try to make `choose[1][1][5]` to be 1, and will next try to make it 7 and so on.

Comment: Thank You so much for the help. I am really trying to get different functions for sudoku as a beginning programmer.